# From in-memory vector to line of code that produces the vector in R

Tags: r

Say I have a vector in some variable `x` that contains all the letters of the alphabet in order.

Is there an easy way in RStudio to get the line of code that would produce that vector? In this case the line would be

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", ...)
```

I looked for a package that does this but didn't find anything.

Comment: Use `dput()` or `dump()`. See the help pages for those functions for more details.